# my Simple render target view is not working

Tags: directx, direct3d, render-to-texture, textureview, rendertarget

i am trying to create another rendertargetview and render it

Before, i just get back buffer from swapchain and then create rtv from it, this works fine. but only when creating rtv from custom resoure, i have a problem.

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC bb_desc;
    bb_desc.Width = width;
    bb_desc.Height = height;
    bb_desc.MipLevels = 1;
    bb_desc.ArraySize = 1;
    bb_desc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    bb_desc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bb_desc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    bb_desc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bb_desc.MiscFlags = 0;
    bb_desc.SampleDesc.Count = msCount;
    bb_desc.SampleDesc.Quality = msQuality;

    R_CHECK(device->CreateTexture2D(
        &bb_desc,
        nullptr,
        backBuffer.GetAddressOf()));

    D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC rtv_desc;
    rtv_desc.Format = bb_desc.Format;
    rtv_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    rtv_desc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
    R_CHECK(device->CreateRenderTargetView(
        backBuffer.Get(),
        &rtv_desc,
        bbRTV.GetAddressOf()));

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srv_desc;
    srv_desc.Format = bb_desc.Format;
    srv_desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    srv_desc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    srv_desc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;
    R_CHECK(device->CreateShaderResourceView(
        backBuffer.Get(),
        &srv_desc,
        bbSRV.GetAddressOf()));

    dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, bbRTV.GetAddressOf(), nullptr);
```

and i render it

```
    float bgColor[3] = { 1,0,0 };
    dContext->ClearRenderTargetView(bbRTV.Get(), bgColor);

    swapchain->Present(1, NULL);
```

expecting red screen, but it is showing just black.
and also there's no error logs.
any advice would be appreciated~

Answer (score 0):

Second argument to `ClearRenderTargetView` is not valid. It must be a pointer to first element of array of 4 `float` values. Since you pass a pointer to the first element of array of 3 `float` value buffer overrun occurs which causes Undefined Behavior.

But most importantly, when you are rendering to texture it won't be presented on screen when you invoke `Present` because it is not a swap chain back buffer. You can inspect texture content using DirectX debugger.

Comment: oh didn't notice that, thanks!.  anyway if i want to render on backbuffer, i may have to just create another geometry and draw it on backbuffer using Draw(). so there might be no way to draw on backbuffer directly i guess.

Comment: @KIMCHANGJUN There is absolutely no problem in drawing directly on the backbuffer.